# How to make a menu item (menu link) invisible in a footer menu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, css

I want to know how to make a menu item (menu link) in a footer menu invisible? You can see it on a print screen I'm attaching to this question. A red arrow and red underlining show which link I'm talking about here. Also here's the link to my live web site (a test site for now).

idevsky.com

It's the "Disclaimer" link, actually.[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to your website administration site
2. Go to Menus -> Your menus which has this menu item

[image]

3. Click on the Unpublish button of the desired menu item

[image]

If you do not want to unpublish and just want to hide it, edit the menu item -> go to Link type tab -> Select No to Display in Menu option

[image]